# How to directly mount NFS share/volume in container using docker compose v3

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have a compose file with v3 where there are 3 services sharing/using the same volume. While using swarm mode we need to create extra containers & volumes to manage our services across the cluster.

I am planning to use NFS server so that single NFS share will get mounted directly on all the hosts within the cluster.

I have found below two ways of doing it but it needs extra steps to be performed on the docker host -

- Mount the NFS share using "fstab" or "mount" command on the host & then use it as a host volume for docker services.
- Use Netshare plugin - https://github.com/ContainX/docker-volume-netshare

Is there a standard way where i can directly use/mount NFS share using docker compose v3 by performing only few/no steps(I understand that "nfs-common" package is required anyhow) on the docker host?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922161/mounting-nfs-shares-inside-docker-container

Answer (score 95, accepted):

After discovering that this is massively undocumented,here's the correct way to mount a NFS volume using stack and docker compose.

The most important thing is that you need to be using `version: "3.2"` or higher. You will have strange and un-obvious errors if you don't.

The second issue is that volumes are **not** automatically updated when their definition changes. This can lead you down a rabbit hole of thinking that your changes aren't correct, when they just haven't been applied. Make sure you `docker rm VOLUMENAME` everywhere it could possibly be, as if the volume exists, it won't be validated.

The third issue is more of a NFS issue - The NFS folder will **not be created** on the server if it doesn't exist. This is just the way NFS works.  You need to make sure it exists before you do anything.

(Don't remove 'soft' and 'nolock' unless you're sure you know what you're doing - this stops docker from freezing if your NFS server goes away)

Here's a complete example:

```
[root@docker docker-mirror]# cat nfs-compose.yml
version: "3.2"

services:
  rsyslog:
    image: jumanjiman/rsyslog
    ports:
      - "514:514"
      - "514:514/udp"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: example
        target: /nfs
        volume:
          nocopy: true
volumes:
  example:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=10.40.0.199,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":/docker/example"



[root@docker docker-mirror]# docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c nfs-compose.yml rsyslog
Creating network rsyslog_default
Creating service rsyslog_rsyslog
[root@docker docker-mirror]# docker stack ps rsyslog
ID                  NAME                IMAGE                       NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE                     ERROR               PORTS
tb1dod43fe4c        rsyslog_rsyslog.1   jumanjiman/rsyslog:latest   swarm-4             Running             Starting less than a second ago
[root@docker docker-mirror]#
```

Now, on swarm-4:

```
root@swarm-4:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d883e0f14d3f        jumanjiman/rsyslog:latest   "rsyslogd -n -f /e..."   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        514/tcp, 514/udp    rsyslog_rsyslog.1.tb1dod43fe4cy3j5vzsy7pgv5
root@swarm-4:~# docker exec -it d883e0f14d3f df -h /nfs
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
:/docker/example          7.2T      5.5T      1.7T  77% /nfs
root@swarm-4:~#
```

This volume will be created (**but not destroyed**) on any swarm node that the stack is running on.

```
root@swarm-4:~# docker volume inspect rsyslog_example
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2017-09-29T13:53:59+10:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "rsyslog"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/rsyslog_example/_data",
        "Name": "rsyslog_example",
        "Options": {
            "device": ":/docker/example",
            "o": "addr=10.40.0.199,nolock,soft,rw",
            "type": "nfs"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
root@swarm-4:~#
```

Comment: I am using NFS with compose v3.1. What type of issues do you think of?
What about possible data-corruption because of the use of soft and nolock? Shouldn't those be addressed in your asnwer?

Comment: @herm maybe xrobau speak about multiple replicas talking to the same nfs server.

Comment: 'soft' lets IO be interrupted.
'nolock' lets flock() calls always succeed. If you're relying on flock() with multiple users on NFS, you're *significantly* slowing down your Disk IO, and you should redesign your application.

Comment: @xrobau, this was what ive been needing to break away from the finicky and troublesome docker volume netshare (DVN) efs driver. when trying this originally, the piece I was missing that lead me to DVN was the "device:" spec under "driver_opts:". thanks.

Comment: Hey, this method means that the IP addresses are hard-coded in to the yml file and can't be changed. Is there a way to set them in side the container scope and then set them using an .env file?

Comment: I believe you can use something like this:  o: addr=host.docker.internal,rw,nolock,hard,nointr,nfsvers=3.  The host.docker.internal address is "magic".

Comment: @GuySoft - Remember that volumes are NOT UPDATED once they are created. Having the IP Address of the NFS server as a variable (which I don't think you can do anyway) will just mean that the NFS mounts will be different on different machines.  The best way to do that is to create a NEW volume (eg, 'example_nfs2') pointing to the other NFS server, and then change the source of the volume in the service definition.

But - seriously - volumes DO NOT GET UPDATED after they are created. It's an easy trap for the unwary.

Answer (score 55):

Depending on how I need to use the volume, I have the following 3 options.

First, you can create the named volume directly and use it as an external volume in compose, or as a named volume in a `docker run` or `docker service create` command.

```
  # create a reusable volume
  $ docker volume create --driver local \
      --opt type=nfs \
      --opt o=nfsvers=4,addr=nfs.example.com,rw \
      --opt device=:/path/to/dir \
      foo
```

Next, there is the `--mount` syntax that works from `docker run` and `docker service create`. This is a rather long option, and when you are embedded a comma delimited option within another comma delimited option, you need to pass some quotes (escaped so the shell doesn't remove them) to the command being run. I tend to use this for a one-off container that needs to access NFS (e.g. a utility container to setup NFS directories):

```
  # or from the docker run command
  $ docker run -it --rm \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,\"volume-opt=o=nfsvers=4,addr=nfs.example.com\",volume-opt=device=:/host/path \
    foo

  # or to create a service
  $ docker service create \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,\"volume-opt=o=nfsvers=4,addr=nfs.example.com\",volume-opt=device=:/host/path \
    foo
```

Lastly, you can define the named volume inside your compose file. One important note when doing this, the name volume only gets created once, and not updated with any changes. So if you ever need to modify the named volume you'll want to give it a new name.

```
  # inside a docker-compose file
  ...
  services:
    example-app:
      volumes:
      - "nfs-data:/data"
  ...
  volumes:
    nfs-data:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: nfs
        o: nfsvers=4,addr=nfs.example.com,rw
        device: ":/path/to/dir"
  ...
```

In each of these examples:

- Type is set to `nfs`, not `nfs4`. This is because docker provides some nice functionality on the `addr` field, but only for the `nfs` type.
- The `o` are the options that gets passed to the mount syscall. One difference between the mount syscall and the mount command in Linux is the device has the portion before the `:` moved into an `addr` option.
- `nfsvers` is used to set the NFS version. This avoids delays as the OS tries other NFS versions first.
- `addr` may be a DNS name when you use `type=nfs`, rather than only an IP address. Very useful if you have multiple VPC's with different NFS servers using the same DNS name, or if you want to adjust the NFS server in the future without updating every volume mount.
- Other options like `rw` (read-write) can be passed to the `o` option.
- The `device` field is the path on the remote NFS server. The leading colon is required. This is an artifact of how the mount command moves the IP address to the `addr` field for the syscall. This directory must exist on the remote host prior to the volume being mounted into a container.
- In the `--mount` syntax, the `dst` field is the path inside the container. For named volumes, you set this path on the right side of the volume mount (in the short syntax) on your `docker run -v` command.

If you get permission issues accessing a remote NFS volume, a common cause I've encountered is containers running as root, with the NFS server set to root squash (changing all root access to the nobody user). You either need to configure your containers to run as a well known non-root UID that has access to the directories on the NFS server, or disable root squash on the NFS server.

Comment: this should be the answer :'(

Comment: @ValerioZhang I'm a bit surprised the other answer got so many more votes since it was posted after this and repeats most everything posted here, but that's how SO works some days.

Comment: yours is the best written, comprehensive, and best of all plug-and-play. *shrug*. thanks again mitch for your contribution!

Comment: Having successfully created an NFS volume, I would like it to be used by more than one container. But each container requires a different directory under that volume. Must I create a volume per directory or is there an extra parameter I can add to specify it? I tried adding the folder in front of the share to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: The Linux mount syscall doesn't allow you to mount a NFS directory that doesn't exist. You need to create the directories before the volumes will mount.

Comment: I followed everything here on docker in the compose file v3.4 on windows container. However, I am getting an error - "Error response from daemon: create bf670d3c790fd64bfaf8e3d2fe33ca211075771602093d8fd8494dffb1572c48: options are not supported on this platform". Do you have any idea?

Comment: @RichaGarg the local volume driver passes the settings to the Linux Kernel's mount syscall. If you are running Windows containers, you don't have the Linux kernel to accept those options.

Comment: @BMitch thanks for the response. Can you please consider this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64430814/best-option-to-access-network-share-in-docker-windows-container-with-docker-comp?

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can directly reference an NFS from the compose file:

```
volumes:
   db-data:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: nfs
        o: addr=$SOMEIP,rw
        device: ":$PathOnServer"
```

And in an analogous way you could create an nfs volume on each host.

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs --opt o=addr=$SomeIP,rw --opt device=:$DevicePath --name nfs-docker
```

Answer (score 5):

My solution for AWS EFS, that works:

1. [Create EFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/gs-step-two-create-efs-resources.html) (don't forget to open NFS port 2049 at security group)
2. Install nfs-common package:

   `sudo apt-get install -y nfs-common`
3. Check if your efs works:

   ```
   mkdir efs-test-point
   sudo chmod go+rw efs-test-point
   ```

   ```
   sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport [YOUR_EFS_DNS]:/ efs-test-point
   ```

   ```
   touch efs-test-point/1.txt
   sudo umount efs-test-point/
   ls -la efs-test-point/
   ```

   > directory must be empty

   ```
   sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport [YOUR_EFS_DNS]:/ efs-test-point
   ```

   `ls -la efs-test-point/`

   > file 1.txt must exists
4. Configure docker-compose.yml file:

   ```
   services:
     sidekiq:
       volumes:
         - uploads_tmp_efs:/home/application/public/uploads/tmp
     ...
   volumes:
     uploads_tmp_efs:
       driver: local
       driver_opts:
         type: nfs
         o: addr=[YOUR_EFS_DNS],nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2
         device: [YOUR_EFS_DNS]:/
   ```

Answer (score 3):

My problem was solved with changing driver option type to NFS4.

```
volumes:
  my-nfs-share:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs4"
      o: "addr=172.24.0.107,rw"
      device: ":/mnt/sharedwordpress"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AutoFS too, on `docker-compose` you may add `:shared` to all paths, like this:

```
volumes:
  - /some/nfs/mounted:/path:shared
```

I found this a better approach to my case thanks to a colleague. Our users were having an error stating 'too many symbolic links'...

Cheers!