# Best option to access network share in docker windows container with Docker Compose

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, windows-container

I am new to docker, so please bear with my naive questions. We are trying to host a dot net application in a Windows container. We were successful in hosting the application in the container. However, the application is accessing the network share like \\machinename\abc. We tried to create a volume of type "NFS" but looks like that does not work well in Windows container([How to directly mount NFS share/volume in container using docker compose v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282608/how-to-directly-mount-nfs-share-volume-in-container-using-docker-compose-v3/56631885?noredirect=1#comment113873706_56631885)).

```
volumes:
  example:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=172.27.11.1,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":/dockerdata"
```

Can anyone please guide what are the options to access the network share in docker windows container?
Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a compose file (with two containers where the "server" needs data from a network share) for docker on windows accessing a volume on a remote windows network share. The "server" container directory /data is mapped to uc3data, the remote share "\\192.168.49.53\myshare$\UC3_DATA"

```
version: '3.7'
volumes:
  uc3data:
    driver_opts:
        type: cifs
        o: "username=${USERNAME},password=${USERPASSWORD}"
        device: "//192.168.49.53/myshare$$/UC3_DATA"
services:
    server:
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            context: ./docker-uc3-multi
        volumes:
            - uc3data:/data
        hostname: uc3multi
        ports:
          - '5000:5000'

    client:
        restart: always
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            context: ./docker-php
        ports:
          - '8080:80'
```

Notes:

- USERPASSWORD and USERNAME are stored in an .env file.
- I used the IP address instead of the name of the remote file server. Name resolution fails in my setup.
- Notice the $$ to escape the $ in the share name