# How to mount AWS EFS inside docker using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I have an efs drive, with shared files, that i want to mount inside docker containers to be run on ECS. AWS has a suggested way to do it using task definition. However,  I want to do it using **docker-compose** and not change task definitions that we manage through console etc.

I am attaching snippet I am using below, but shared drive doesn't get mounted and gives following error per below. It comes as empty and doesnt show shared efs. Can someone suggests as to what am I doing incorrectly here and how can i change dockerfile or docker-compose yml to get desired results.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  server:
    build: .
    image: xyz
    command: "gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.server:server -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: efs_volume
        target: /mnt/efs_xyz
volumes:
  efs_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs4"
      o: "addr=fs-xxxxxx.efs.useast1.amazonaws.com,rw,nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport"
      device: ":/"
```

Below is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update -y &&  apt-get install -y \
    vim \
    g++ \
    unixodbc-dev \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt Docker* docker* .docker* ./app/

RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

**Error when running docker-compose up**

```
Cannot start service server: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/app_efs_volume/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/:/var/lib/docker/volumes/app_efs_volume/_data, data: addr=fs-0bb4dbbf.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com,nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport: invalid argument
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282608/how-to-directly-mount-nfs-share-volume-in-container-using-docker-compose-v3#answer-56631885), only `type: nfs` (not `type: nfs4`) allows to use `addr=<hostname>`.

Comment: I think it would be better to link the documentation instead of another answer anyway