# docker-compose share volume of other machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, share

I am using docker which created on windows 10 (The docker is for linux).

Also, using docker-compose (Version 3.4) to map a volumes that is outside docker into the docker container.

I have a shared folder on another computer, that I want to use in the docker.

I check the access of that folder, and I can access it from the computer the docker is running.

//ip_addr/shared_folder

In docker-compose, I wrote:

```
volumes:
  - //1.2.3.4/my_folder:my_docker_folder
```

I found some syntax with networks declaration.
I don't know how exactly shall I write?

```
volumes:
  - /my_folder:my_docker_folder
networks:
  frontend:
    ipv4_address: 1.2.3.4
```

and that ip 1.2.3.4 is the ip for my_folder?

... but this syntax may not be correct, or I should run some commands to share the folder correctly.

What to do in order to map the other computer shared folder to the docker.

**I have tried several things, also mapping a symbolic link.**

I am trying create a symbolic link in windows 10 and attach it to docker, but this doesn't much helped me, since I encountered into exception.

In windows command line I did:

```
mklink /D c:\test_ext \\ip\shared_folder
```

When running the docker (I have the docker community edition Version 
18.06.1-ce-win73 (19507) - linux container).

In command line, I have tried to run alpine (that's happens also on other dockers based on linux images):

docker run -i -t -v c:\test_ext:/data:rw alpine /bin/sh
I get the error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source
>   path '/host_mnt/c/test_ext': mkdir /host_mnt/c/test_ext: file exists.

That's only happen for external IP.

What I see, is that the folder+subfolders+files is shared with full permissions.

I have tried some work around, such as: docker volumes prune, but this didn't much help.

Why is that error message, and how can I resolve that?

I found also, an alternative that may help:

```
docker volume create \
  --driver local \
  --opt type=nfs \
  --opt o=addr=ip_address,rw \
  --opt device=:/myfolder 
   my_volume
```

This doesn't solve the problem either (syntax is wrong).

Thanks.

Comment: Just to make debugging easier, if I were you I'd try changing to the long syntax https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes this however does look like your issue is just how windows works with network drives rather than docker. But I can't be sure as I haven't used docker in this way.

Comment: You can write c# core in windows, but the docker is suitable for linux. Just put the //machine_name or //ip_name as source, but it seems not to be the correct syntax (or it is the correct syntax, but I need to do some extra steps).

Comment: Do you have the same issue with the long syntax from the documentation I linked? Also worth checking your versions to make sure you're up to date since long syntax was added not that long ago

Comment: I use version 3.4. I don't use web. Just a folder shared on another computer. Still I didn't understand what syntax can solve this issue. Any good yml sample for exactly situation which I want to use shared folder of another computer from the current folder?

Comment: I found: that network may be the solution. I don't know how exactly shall I write?

    volumes:
      - /my_folder:my_docker_folder
    networks:
      frontend:
        ipv4_address: 1.2.3.4

and that ip 1.2.3.4 is the ip for my_folder. Is that the correct syntax? is there any good example for that?

Comment: This is a very good question, curious myself the answer.

Comment: I edited my post accordinally. Why simple thing of sharing files, may be complicated issue. I am sure there must be a syntax way doing that.

Comment: I think I can install samba into the docker, and may use it in docker-compose (in some manner). How can I map an external volume in docker in that way?

Comment: The solution may be related to creating symbol links or volumes with mapping. I tried that way, but I encountered into a new problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53703329/create-a-symbolic-link-in-windows-and-attach-it-to-docker

Comment: Maybe try using the [Netshare](https://github.com/ContainX/docker-volume-netshare) plugin? [#39922331](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39922331/6085135)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you need to give . near the volume 
`volumes:
  - ./my_folder:my_docker_folder`

Comment: Windows default file system is CIFS. That's never for for me for windows environment.