# How to mount EFS inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, amazon-efs

I am trying to mount EFS inside a docker container running on EC2 server. EFS mount in EC2 is working fine with,

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport <efs-address>:/ efs
```

But when tried in docker container, it is giving error 'mount.nfs4: Operation not permitted'. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mounting nfs shares inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922161/mounting-nfs-shares-inside-docker-container)

Comment: Is creating a `docker` volume and using that not an option? e.g. `docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs --opt o=addr=10.0.0.50,rw,nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 --opt device=:/ efs` then using the volume `docker run --rm -it -v efs:/mnt ubuntu:18.04`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a `docker volume` using EFS:

```
docker volume create \
    --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt o=addr=10.0.0.50,rw,nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 \
    --opt device=:/ efs
```

Then mount the volume `docker run --rm -it -v efs:/mnt ubuntu:18.04`.

Comment: This works as per my requirement, but there is one catch. This needs two steps: 1. Create docker volume, 2. Run docker image. Is it possible to have a single step for this? Can I change my dockerfile somehow to do this job?

Comment: @padmanabhpande can't do anything with the `Dockerfile` itself, if using `docker-compose` then you could define the `docker volume` there and it would create the `docker volume` if it doesn't already exist when bringing up the service(s).

Answer (score 0):

## For docker-compose file:

Please replace aws_efs_host to your EFS DNS name.

```yaml
volumes:
  volume_name:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=aws_efs_host,rw,nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport
      device: ":/"
```

## References

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs-mount-helper-ec2-linux.html