# Share a FUSE mount between containers in docker compose without persisting anything on host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount, docker-volume, fuse

It's quite straightforward how to share a volume between containers when they share the FS, however it gets more complicated when one endpoint targets a directory that not only has a different FS but also this FS changes after the container runs, and the other one wants to replicate it (ro mode).

An important part is that the shared volume should **not** be stored on the host machine. It should only "live" between the containers and not be persistent.

The snippet below **won't** work, it's just to give an idea on what I am trying to achieve (see comments).

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  # This service spins up with /mnt being an empty, unmounted dir.
  # It then runs an executable that will mount a FUSE filesystem
  # under /mnt
  app:
    # application
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: shared_mnt
        target: /mnt
        bind:
          propagation: shared
    privileged: true
    devices:
      - '/dev/fuse'

  # This service wants to read (read-only) the contents of this
  # FUSE fs from `app` service, thus it should act as a slave
  nginx: 
    # nginx
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: shared_mnt
        target: /whateve # a read-only replica of `app`'s /mnt dir (does not have to be a fuse FS)
        bind:
          propagation: shared

volumes:
  shared_mnt:
```

Comment: Not persisting the data to disk and sharing the volume isn't possible using a [`tmpfs`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/). Using a `bind-mount` volume will persist the files to disk. You could back the volume with an NFS share i.e. [EFS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57742017/1423507) but then the data will be persisted to the NFS servers disk. You can look through the existing `volume plugins` if anything fits your requirements but I'm not aware anything that you can `docker volume create` with that would store the data in memory and which can be shared between containers.

Comment: Could probably run an [`nfs-server-alpine`](https://hub.docker.com/r/itsthenetwork/nfs-server-alpine) NFS server in `docker` backed by a `tmpfs` volume then configure your services to output their volumes to that NFS server instance.

Comment: This sounds like a nice workaround. Thanks for the suggestion @masseyb