# Docker swarm is not correctly copying volumes across other worker nodes

Tags: php, docker, nginx, swarm

I'm trying to build a Laravel application (LEMP Stack) in Docker Swarm. I'm using [HaProxy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/), as described in Dockers networking documentation on ingress networks, to load balance from the manager nodes public IPV4 between all worker nodes.

My current configuration looks like so:

```
frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   stats uri /haproxy?stats
   default_backend http_back

frontend http_front_ssl
    bind *:443
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    default_backend http_back_ssl

backend http_back
   balance roundrobin
   server vps1 xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080 check
   server vps2 xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080 check
   server vps3 xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080 check

backend http_back_ssl
   balance roundrobin
   server vps1 xx.xx.xxx.xxx:4043 check
   server vps2 xx.xx.xxx.xxx:4043 check
   server vps3 xx.xx.xxx.xxx:4043 check
```

I have then a custom image that provides and exposes a PHP-FPM on port 9000:

```
docker service create \
--name php-fpm \
--replicas=3 \
--network app-net \
--secret source=proxy.conf,target=/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf \
--secret site.key \
--secret site.crt \
--mount type=volume,src=web,dst=/var/www \
jaquarh/php-fpm:alpha
```

The keys are for self-signed SSL (testing Https). The Dockerfile to build this is:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
COPY laravel/composer.lock laravel/composer.json /var/www/
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN pecl install memcached; \
    docker-php-ext-install intl; \
    docker-php-ext-install exif; \
    echo "extension=memcached.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini; \
    docker-php-ext-enable exif;

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

COPY . /var/www
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

USER www

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

I am then building an nginx service as the proxy for the php-fpm service.

```
docker service create \
--name nginx \
--secret site.key \
--secret site.crt \
--secret source=site.conf,target=/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf \
-p 8080:80 \
-p 4043:443 \
--replicas=3 \
--network app-net \
--mount type=volume,src=web,dst=/var/www \
nginx:latest \
sh -c "exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

Inside of my `web` volume, I hold all the laravel files. I am only testing Http at the moment so my nginx configuration looks like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.co.uk; # this is my actual domain for testing

    index index.php index.html;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /var/www/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

   location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
       access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
   }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # ready for when letsencrypt is introduced
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
       allow all;
       root /var/www/html;
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a pre-built SQL database volume and service ready to use which the laravel `.env` uses.

```
docker service create \
--name mysql \
--replicas=3 \
--network app-net \
--secret site.key \
--secret site.crt \
--mount type=volume,src=dbdata,target=/var/lib/mysql/ \
--env MYSQL_DATABASE=xxxxxx \
--env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxx \
--env MYSQL_USER=xxxxx \
--env MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxxxx \
-p 3306:3306 \
mysql:latest
```

The issue I am facing is that VPS1 (in this case the manager) gets these files perfectly fine because the volumes exist in the manager VPS. Both VPS2 and VPS3 show these volumes have been mounted correctly but are not copying the data over.

[image: Mount]

[image: Different]

As seen in the images, on my development pc (which is also a worker for testing) I can see the mount has been successfully created and my docker is assigned the nginx container however, when I inspect the directories in bash, only the directory housing the laravel application exists in the manager node.

What am I doing wrong? How can I copy this volume across my worker nodes? If I inspect the volume on the manager it looks like this:

```
ubuntu@vps-438f3f94:~$ docker volume inspect web
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-04-23T09:29:23Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/web/_data",
        "Name": "web",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

**Update:** If I look at the HaProxy stats, I can see my development PC is `DOWN` because I'm not port forwarded (as its just for me to debug containers) but I'm assuming this has no real effect on volumes but just to give you an insight to my environment better.

```
http_back   
Queue   Session rate    Sessions    Bytes   Denied  Errors  Warnings    Server
Cur Max Limit   Cur Max Limit   Cur Max Limit   Total   LbTot   Last    In  Out Req Resp    Req Conn    Resp    Retr    Redis   Status  LastChk Wght    Act Bck Chk Dwn Dwntme  Thrtle
vps1    0   0   -   0   3       0
1   -   38
38  25m15s  14191   23441       0       0   0   0   0   25m30s UP   L4OK in 0ms 1   Y   -   28  10  0s  -
vps2    0   0   -   0   1       0
1   -   30
30  25m6s   10055   16896       0       0   0   0   0   25m28s UP   L4OK in 0ms 1   Y   -   30  10  0s  -
vps3    0   0   -   0   0       0
0   -   0
0   ?   0   0       0       0   0   0   0   13h5m DOWN  * L4TOUT in 2001ms  1   Y   -   1   1   13h5m   -
Backend 0   0       0   8       0   1   26212   121
68  25m6s   43399   52050
0   0       53  0   0   0   25m30s UP       2   2   0       9   2h20m
```

Comment: [`docker` volumes are local to the node on which they are created, they are not shared or synced between `docker swarm` nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64246878/1423507). You can back the `docker volume`(s) with a Network File System that can be mounted in RW on multiple nodes.

Comment: Thanks for this useful information and with the link provided I can look into networking the volume. Would this be done using the public IPV4 on the manager node? I'm also not using docker-compose so does anything change here? I can [see on my vp2 that this is indeed the case](https://imgur.com/a/C86hrVP) and the volumes are not being shared @masseyb

Comment: You need an NFS server somewhere, wouldn't suggest exposing it on the WAN. For development you could [run an NFS server in docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/itsthenetwork/nfs-server-alpine/), e.g. you'd create a volume and mount it to the NFS server container then create the `docker volume`(s) backed by the NFS service. Depending on where you're deploying for production, [AWS provides EFS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57742017/1423507), GCP provides Filestore, etc.

Comment: Right, so my infrastructure is incorrect for the  matter at hand and I'll need to configure a NAS sort of approach with the volumes. I see from a google search that this means that development updates is easier because the NSF server would control any code-related changes thus only then needing to restart the containers on updates @masseyb

Comment: Correct - yeah, sounds about right, unless laravel auto-reloads on changes then you'd probably need to bounce the containers, not sure to be honest, I don't use Laravel, just swarm / kubernetes with volumes shared between containers running on different nodes.

Comment: I'm new into Containerised applications - let alone clusters but I like to learn new things. You seem exceptionally knowledgeable in the field - perhaps we could collaborate? Expand both sides of the devops cycle. [I set up a chat room with SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231514/docker-swarm-laravel) it'd be great to talk further. @masseyb