# How to automate Gitlab backups to a remote server

Tags: docker, centos, gitlab-ci, windows-server-2012

I have one Debian based server in which I have a centos virtual machine. This VM has a docker container in which I have Gitlab installed. I have another server with Windows Server 2012 installed I want to send the Gitlab backups from the Debian server to the windows server daily. I have read the Gitlab backup documentation but I am not able to get the answer from it.

Anyone here has any good method, please answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Uploading to locally mounted shares](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html#uploading-to-locally-mounted-shares), you can create an SMB share on your Windows Server 2012, and [mount it on your Gitlab docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39922161/7641078).

Then you need to configure Gitlab `backup_upload_connection` to use `Local` as storage provider and specify `local_root` as your mounted directory. e.g.:

```
gitlab_rails['backup_upload_connection'] = {
  :provider => 'Local',
  :local_root => '/mnt/backups'
}

# The directory inside the mounted folder to copy backups to
# Use '.' to store them in the root directory
gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory'] = 'gitlab_backups'
```