# why the docker root user mount permission denied

Tags: docker

when I am mount volume in docker with root user like this:

```
# mount -t nfsxxxx-pli55.cn-shanghai.nas.aliyuncs.com:/k8s/reddwarf-pro/chat-server-service /home/nfs/
mount: /home/nfs: permission denied.
```

shows permission denied, then I tried to use this command:

```
chmod -R 777 /home/nfs
```

and rerun the bind command, still shows that the permission denied. why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this issue? why could not use the mount command with root user?

Comment: You can't normally mount filesystems inside a Docker container, whether from a debug shell or anywhere else.  Can you mount the filesystem somewhere else, maybe as a named volume, and attach it to the container at startup time?

Comment: [Mount SMB/CIFS share within a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989751/mount-smb-cifs-share-within-a-docker-container) discusses the Linux capability restriction that's causing the error.  [Mounting nfs shares inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922161/mounting-nfs-shares-inside-docker-container) describes a pure-Docker workflow in its [accepted answer](/a/45911186).

Comment: I created a nfs pv and pvc and I want to test the mount command.

Comment: If this is in a Kubernetes context, the previous links won't work for you.  Mount the PersistentVolumeClaim in your Deployment spec.  Don't try to do things (and especially administration-type commands) in `kubectl exec` shells: in Kubernetes especially, they'll only affect one replica of your Deployment, and it's possible for the cluster to automatically delete a Pod in some circumstances and your changes will be lost.